# How do (can?) I write a class that extends a class and a subclass

Tags: java

I have a question that I am not sure has an answer, but its worth a shot because I would like to not have to maintain two copies of code.

I have a library where class B is a subclass of class A. I have written myself a class C, which extends class A. I would like to make it so that B extends C rather than A, however because A and B are 3rd party libraries for which I do not have source, I do not know how to do this.

Currently, the only solution I know is to make a copy of my class C as a class D, and have it extend B, then refer to D rather than B in my code.

I guess in other words, I am trying to extend a superclass, that then propagates to subclasses.

I hope this post is coherent enough.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Can't be done; shouldn't be done.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `class B extends A` and `class C extends A`. You want B to extend C.

Comment: Yes; A and B are part of the library.

Comment: I'm confused... you say that you want `B extend C`, but a possible alternative is to create `D` such that `C == D` and `D extend B`.  Doesn't that mean you want `C extend B`?  You have control of `C`, so make it extend `B`.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a situation where you might want to consider having your classes delegate to the library classes rather than subclassing them.

Then you should be able to have one class with whatever abilities you're adding, and access the functions of A and B by delegation.

Depending on the details of what you're actually doing, this might be a [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

With more details on what these classes do, I might be able to give a clearer suggestion...

Answer (score -1):

Think about what you'd really like to do: you have classes A, B, and C where

```
      A
     / \
    B   C
```

Of these, you wrote C; A and B are third party.  You want C to be a sub class of B, which would simply be:

```
      A
     / 
    B  
   /
  C
```

That's not conceptually a problem, rewrite C so you have

```
  class A {}
  class B extends A {}
```

Those are both third party and unchangeable.  Now you have

```
  class C extends B {}
```

and that gives what you describe.  However, since you're finding it hard, I suspect you may have something like clashing method names.  If so, the aggregation is your friend:

```
 class Cprime {
    A a;
    B b;
```

and now write new methods for everything you want to include from either A or B.

Comment: Actually, the way he describes it, the end result he is going for would be:
`class B extends C {}`, rather than `class C extends B {}` He wants to  "insert" his own class in the inheritance tree, between A and C.